# Finding the Torsion given a vector r[t]

Tags: vector

How do I find the torsion of a vector?
The function is:

```
    r[t_]:={Sin[7t],t^4,Cos[7t]}
```

Comment: `FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t][[1]]`

Comment: `r[t_] = {Sin[7 t], t^4, Cos[7 t]};
FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t][[1, 2]]`

Comment: As an alternative to the reply by @cvgmt you can code it yourself as follows `FullSimplify[Norm[r'[t].Cross[r''[t], r'''[t]]]/
 Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]]^2, t > 0]`. [Useful material for my approach can be found here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torsion.html). I have also checked that both approaches yield the same result as they should

Comment: What I mean is that this `FullSimplify[Norm[r'[t].Cross[r''[t], r'''[t]]]/
  Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]]^2, t > 0] - 
 FullSimplify[FrenetSerretSystem[r[t], t][[1, 2]]]` returns `0`