# Finding the Curvature of the path of a particle

Tags: vector, vector-calculus

How do I find the curvature of the vector when t=5?

The function is:

```
    v[t_] := {2 t^4 + 2, 6 t^3 + 1, 3 t^2 + 4}
```

Comment: Please read my comment! https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264624/finding-the-torsion-given-a-vector-rt

Comment: `FrenetSerretSystem[v[t], t][[1,1]]/.t->5`

Comment: @cvgmt as you can see from my answer, I kind of guessed the `FrenetSerretSystem` and was hoping that you'd write an answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
v[t_] := {2 t^4 + 2, 6 t^3 + 1, 3 t^2 + 4}

curv = ArcCurvature[v[t], t]
```

You sent `t` to `5` like so:

```
N[curv /. t -> 5]
```

There's another way but I am letting this up to @cvgmt to show it